# Django return specific field from model as foreign key

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am creating a class in Django's models.py. When I am creating a second class where I have a foreign key from the first class. The key is "1" or "2" or ...

I wonder if you can set up Django to use a specific field to use as key.

For example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    myid = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Setting(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    ...
```

Then I have a view

```
def getsetting(request):
    response = serializers.serialize('json', Setting.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='json')
```

The json returned shows "1", "2", ... as key for the field "owner".

So my question is, if I could use "name" or "myid" as foreign key? Or is there a simple way to overwrite these field in the json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify primary_key=True on one of your fields." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

So, you can change your class Customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    myid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
```

Comment: Really simple way! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at serialization with natural keys. You can read the official docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/#natural-keys

It is fairly simple, just add a method to your class:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    myid = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.myid, )
```

And then serialize with `use_natural_foreign_keys=True`:

```
def getsetting(request):
    response = serializers.serialize('json', Setting.objects.all(), 
                                     use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
    return HttpResponse(response, content_type='json')
```